# Copying text from another application into a Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I enter text manually in a sharepoint list, it looks like this in HTML:

```
<div>
This is a test
</div>
```

But when I copy text from another application into a sharepoint list, it looks like this in HTML:

```
<div>
<p>
This is a test
</p>
</div)
```

SharePoint puts it the copied text between a paragraph tag. How can I prevent this.
Or how can I get ride of the paragraph tags?

Gr,

Peter kiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which type of the field did you use?

If you use Multiple lines of text with Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks), you will get the HTML like below.

```
<div>
    <p>
        This is a test
    </p>
</div>
```

If you only want to store the text, we can use Plain text of the Multiple lines of text to achieve it.

[image]